# Bump Map Painting - Low Resolution (Cycles)

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to paint a bump map but it's not looking so good. Am I doing something wrong?

[image: I created a new 4k texture]
I created a new 4k texture

[image: Created a material with a bump node connected to a glossy shader]
Created a material with a bump node connected to a glossy shader

[image: I don't know if its correct...i would like a smoothier bump]
It's not looking correct. Can i enable, somehow, a high res painting?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solved the issue? i have it too now

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue too, I think its caus when creating the image theres a option for 16 bit / 32 bit image and you should use that rather.

And change the image nodes Linear to > Smart.